# Public Rest API Use-case testing (e.g. converts @ into %40)

Tags: rest, http

Is there a public Web API that I can use to test my calls? Maybe specifically for get requests? 
For example:

- /async/takeslongtime : Tests how your application acts when you do an API call that takes a long time
- /params/encoding?exactstring=!@# : Tests if you are encododing as %21%40%23
- Something with path parameters maybe
- Anything else I should bother testing for (multiple parameters, etc)

Or, what things did I not mention that I should test for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the url of the sample REST Service "http://httpbin.org/". 
Navigating to the endpoint display's all the available resources and its supported methods.

For Example:

1. /delay/:n -> Helps you create the delay.
2. /response-headers?key=val -> for testing encoding

It also provides endpoints that can be used for testing various other HTTP methods.
This will mostly meet your requirements.